# How to programatically add an image to a textblock?

Tags: c#, image, windows-8, tablet-pc

I'm trying to set an icon to be attached to a textblock when it is saved but I'm not sure how I would do this programatically.What I'm thinking is you could set the value to the left of the textbox to an image.I have tried this but I'm not sure how I would set it to an image icon:

`NoteGridView.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty(double)block.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty));`

This is how I'm adding the notes to the layout:

```
// Creates a new textblock that for this note.
TextBlock block = new TextBlock();
//block.SetValue
notepadTxtBox.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, (double)block.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty));
block.Width = 250;
block.Height = 125;
block.Text = notepadTxtBox.Text;


// Add that note to the grid.
NoteGridView.Items.Add(block);
```

Does anyone have any idea how I would acheive this or is it possible to do in the xaml code?

This might give a better understanding of what I'm trying to do:

[image: How it currently looks:]
[image: Trying to add an icon to the left of the note like in this picture:]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put a `StackPanel` inside of the `TextBlock`, containing an `Image`, and another `TextBlock`, like so:

```
<TextBlock>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Name="YourImage" Source="image/Under-Construction.png" />
        <TextBlock Text="Your Text Block Text" />
    </StackPanel>
</TextBlock>
```

You would then be able to set the Image programmatically like so:

```
YourImage.Source = "path.to.image.file"
```

Comment: Are you sure that a `StackPanel` can be a child of a `TextBlock`?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud, yes.  I tested it before posting the code to avoid the embarassment of providing false information :)  a `StackPanel` can definitely be a child of a `TextBlock`.